# How do records get ordered in a mysql group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

so suppose I do

```
SELECT * FROM table t GROUP BY t.id
```

Suppose there are multiple rows in the table with the same id, only one row of that id will ultimately come out...I suppose mysql will order the results that have the same id and the return the first one or something....my question is...how does mysql perform this ordering and is there a way that I can control its ordering so that for instance, it uses a certain field etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` several different columns to arrange the order for which the result is grouped.

```
SELECT * FROM table t GROUP BY t.id, t.foo, t.bar
```

Comment: This is precisely opposite from what the MySQL documentation states: "Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause."  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html.

Answer (score 0):

In strictly correct SQL, when you use GROUP BY all the values being selected must be either columns named in the GROUP BY clause or aggregate functions. MySQL allows you to violate this rule, unless you set the `only_full_group_by` mode. But although it allows you to perform such queries, it doesn't specify which row will be selected for each grouped column.

If you want to select a row that corresponds to the max or min of some other column, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table a
JOIN (SELECT id, max(somecol) maxcol
      FROM table
      GROUP BY id) b
ON a.id = b.id
AND a.somecol = b.maxcol
```

Note that this can still return multiple rows per ID if they both have the max value. You can add a final GROUP BY clause and it will select one of them arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

When using this MySQL extension to the standard SQL GROUP BY functionality you cannot control which values for the non-aggregated, non-GROUP BY columns are selected by the server.  The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) discusses this specific case and states clearly that

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they
>   are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the
>   selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an
>   ORDER BY clause.